# C++ Send packet through UDP but not receiving it

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, client-server

I'm currently working on a project need to broadcast the data packet to a common port D88 for every second, but the client can not receive the data packet. I'm not sure I'm using the right way to send the packet.

```
int sockfdBroad;
struct sockaddr_in addrBroad;
swStat.packetBroadSent=0;

sockfdBroad=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);


bzero(&addrBroad,sizeof(addrBroad));
addrBroad.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrBroad.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.255");
addrBroad.sin_port=htons(3464);   


if ((cycles%1000)==0)
    {

        currenttime = getMicrosTimeStamp();
        createTimePacket(bufferTime,currenttime,Odroid_Trigger);
        sendto(sockfdBroad,bufferTime,PACKET_LENGTH_TIME,0,(struct sockaddr *)&addrBroad,sizeof(addrBroad));
        swStat.packetBroadSent++;
    }
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show any call to `recvfrom` (or read). You need it to receive UDP packets via socket. Please, check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you mean the server can not receive the data packet? Could provide the receiver code?

Comment: Run a sniffer on sender machine and check if packet ever sent. Then investigate your network.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the netmask for 192.168.1.255 is 255.255.255.0, 192.168.1.255 is a broadcast address. From [`man ip(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

> Datagrams to broadcast addresses can be only sent or received when the `SO_BROADCAST` socket flag is set.

In other words, both the sender and the receiver must do:

```
int value = 1;
if(-1 == setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &value, sizeof value))
    // Handle error.
```

---

If you check the return value of `sendto` it must be -1 and `errno == EACCESS`. **Always check the return values.**